# Replace a tag element property on a page using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to wrap my head around building a simple Chrome extension that replaces a certain tag's property on a webpage.

The site  has the following code:

```
<body ondragstart="return false;" onselectstart="return false;">
```

thus making text on the web page unselectable. I'm trying to make the text selectable.

I tried this code in my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {         
    $('body').live('selectstart dragstart', function (evt) {
        evt.allowDefault();
        return true;
    });
});
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){               
    var bd = document.getElementById('body');
    bd.addEventListener('selectstart', start, true);
    bd.addEventListener('dragstart', start, true);
});
```

My manifest is as follows:

```
{
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "chav.jpg"
   },
   "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "jquery.js", "content_script.js" ],
      "matches": [ "http://www.chavaramatrimony.com/*" ]
   } ],
   "description": "Lets you select text",
   "icons": {
      "128": "chav.jpg"
   },

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "ChavaraMatrimony Unlocker",
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.1"
}
```

None of them seem to work. The console shows an error: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".

I would be glad for some help on what I'm doing wrong going about this.

Comment: Probably not including jQuery as a content script before your own code? You should include your manifest.json in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the root of your problem is that your code is running in [isolated context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), that cannot access nor override page context's handlers.

See this answer for [injecting your code into the page's context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/934239).

Also note, that you probably should not be looking to add another listener, but to clear existing ones.

Comment: Thank you.That sounds logical.